# Show alert after dismissing multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

I have the following view controller flow:

```
Controller A -> Controller B -> Controller C -> Controller D
```

In Controller D, when I dismiss it, it dismisses controllers D, C, and B, so that it shows Controller A again. Now, what I want to do is show an alert controller in Controller A when Controller D is dismissed.

I know I can create a delegate/protocol so that I call a specific function when Controller D is dismissed, but this really only works well when it's between two controllers, not four.

So what would the best solution here be? The only other thing I've thought of doing is creating an SQL table where I update the value of `showAlertController` to `true` and then check if that value is true in Controller A, but this seems like bad practice and a bit hacky.

Answer (score 3):

One way of achieving this is by sending notification from Controller D to Controller A by using `NotificationCenter` .

In general Controller A will listen for done/dismiss notification that Controller D will send.

[NotificationCenter  Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)

Answer (score 2):

Basically three steps are needed to achieve this, using NotificationCenter.

- post notification when D view controller is dismissed

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let Ddismissed = Notification.Name("Ddismissed")
}

// use below code when you want to dismiss D, C, B
dismiss(animated: true) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .Ddismissed, object: nil)
}
```

- add observer to listen to the event, and show alert view controller after that

```
// add this code to view controller A's viewDidLoad func
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAlert), name: .Ddismissed, object: nil)
```

- do whatever you want in showAlert func

```
@objc func showAlert() {
    //show your alert view controller
}
```

Hope this helps :)